# HTTP request handled by apache but not by Laravel?

Tags: laravel, apache, http, xmlhttprequest

I have a Laravel7 app to which I send large data files (mp3/wav) and a CSV file via XHR to a POST method.
Generally, the stuff works like a charm, but for one of my testers (slower connection), it works randomly.

The thing is that I see in my Apache logs that the request is accepted, and responded with a 200 status code. The Laravel log doesn't show anything (I put some Log::debug at the start on my controller action).

If I test by myself, the log show what it has to.

In my /etc/php.ini, I set higher values for max_execution_time (3600), max_input_time(3600), post_max_size(4G), and upload_max_filesize(4G).
In my  virtualhost conf, I set a TimeOut value to 3600.

Also, it seems, that when my tester sends the csv file as raw text file (.txt), the app responds, but I cannot figureout why, as we have no blocking concerning the non-audio file ...

Have you any idea ?

THanks in advance.

Comment: Both your Apache's access log & error log show no anomaly?

Comment: The error.log stays empty, the access.log shows usual, normal information. The calls to the URL which processes the form are responded with 200 status codes.

Comment: The PHP error log remains empty also.